# Range-doppler surface

Tags: signal-processing, radar

I'm reading a paper "Through-the-Wall Sensing of Personnel Using
Passive Bistatic WiFi Radar at Standoff Distances" for an academic assignment.

The paper has a number of references to "Range-doppler surface". What is a range-Doppler surface?

> This section summarizes the matched filter signal processing employed in passive radar systems to generate range–Doppler surfaces. We will see later, in Section IV-B, that the range–Doppler surface can be iteratively deconstructed to remove the unwanted elements, such as clutter and DSI.

Comment: What does google say?

Comment: Google wasn't very helpful. I found a number of white papers that referenced the keyword, and two sets of lecture slides, but non actually explained it. It was written under the pretense that you were already familiar with the terminology. Hence, I posted on here as a last resort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The range-Doppler surface is also called the ambiguity function.  Matched filter signal processing of radar signals is equivalent to the cross-correlation of the received signal with a replica of the transmitted signal shifted in time and frequency.  The time shift corresponds to target range and the frequency shift corresponds to target Doppler (velocity). The ambiguity function is the magnitude of the cross-correlation process as a function of the time shift and the frequency shift.  It is usually plotted as a 3D graph where the x axis is the time shift, the y axis is the frequency shift and the height at any point is the magnitude of the ambiguity function.  The plot is a surface and is referred to as the range-Doppler surface. The values of the surface at any point shows how well the radar can detect the range and velocity of a target at that XY value of range and velocity. Generally, for long radar pulses, the time (range) resolution is low but the frequency shift (Doppler) resolution is high.  For short radar pulses, the range resolution is high but the Doppler resolution is low. To get good range and Doppler resolution, more complex transmit waveforms are used such as FM slides. Google ambiguity function and cross-correlation processing for more information.